# Miniumum optimal solar panels MPPT Range vs Max

Tags: inverter

I have installed a Growatt SPF 3000TL HVM-48 PV Off-grid Inverter with a 3.5KW battery at my mother-in-law.  I want to get a few panels to keep the tv, internet and lights on and when abundant, can keep the cats warm with a 300w panel.  Given the Max PV input voltage is 145VDC and the range is 60-115VDC, would it be acceptable to run 3 panels in series, i.e 3 x 555W panels (Open Circuit Voltage (VOC): 49.8V / Optimal Operating Voltage (Vmp): 41.9V).  Based on calc: 3 x 49.8V = 149.4V (max) & 3 x 41.9 = 125.7V (typical).  I'm not concerned about losing a few V's, but am concerned if we exceed the VOC.  At my geo, we typically will get over 1KW/m2.

Can I get away with 3 panels in series (safely) or do I need to get 4 series & parallel?  I am trying to save money.